# WebFormApp Insert into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, textbox

So, I have all from Tutorial and should work! But the GridView fills with Data Finaly but does not save into Database!

```
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Objekt(Name, Beschreibung) values(@Name , @Beschreibung)", conn);


        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Beschreibung", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;

        cmd.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();

        MessageBox.Show(" Daten erfolgreich eingefügt! ");

        showdata();
    }
```

This is how I try to insert the Data, so like I've said the GridView does appear that the Data is entered! But after I reopen the App all is Empty. even if I look into Database antries them stay blank!

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SqlDataSource1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter adpt;
    DataTable dt;
```

This is how I connect to the Database and Connection!

```
        public void showdata()
    {
        adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Objekt", conn);
        dt = new DataTable();
        adpt.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Objekt] (
[ObjektID]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]         VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[Beschreibung] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ObjektID] ASC)
```

So ShowData is for the GridView to Fill it with the Tables Data! I Guess there is something wrong how it should finaly insert all into Database!

Can maybe someone provide me with an Code Example how should it be, to insert into Database with an TextBox?

So like I've said I have this codes from an Tutorial.

```
        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Diese Codezeile lädt Daten in die Tabelle "sqlDataSource1DataSet.Objekt". Sie können sie bei Bedarf verschieben oder entfernen.
        this.objektTableAdapter.Fill(this.sqlDataSource1DataSet.Objekt);

    }
```

maybe this is the Problem?

Comment: Do you get any error messages from database? What does `showdata` do? Could you provide the database structure?

Comment: Where do I see Error Messages from DataBase?

Comment: End the error is???..........

Comment: I did not see any Error!

Comment: the code looks ok. did you look in the database if the data is really not stored? if it is not stored after `executenonquery` there must be an error message. you can look for the data in sql server explorer in visual studio

Comment: also sometimes datagrid does not like to update the datasource. try `dataGridView1.DataSource = null;` before `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`

Comment: I have tryed select * from Objekt in sqlquery but results are empty! And I get no Error Messages!

Comment: I have even DataSets!

Comment: 1. if you write to someone, add his/her user tag like @SarsmasAhangari. 2. try this - `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txt.Text).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;`

Comment: Thanks for the Reply it was an Database problem had to reinstall all, I had uninstalled something and the problem was there.